# Show that the following matrices in $\mathbb C^{2\times2}$ are similar over the field $\mathbb C$.

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations, change-of-basis, similar-matrices

How to find a matrix $P$ invertible such that $PA=BP$ where,

$$A=
    \begin{pmatrix}
    cos\theta & -sin\theta  \\
    sin\theta & cos\theta  \\
    \end{pmatrix}
$$ and $$B=
    \begin{pmatrix}
    e^{i\theta} & 0  \\
    0 & e^{-i\theta}  \\
    \end{pmatrix}
$$
Is there any operation to find $P$.If I try to find the roots of $λ^2−2λcosθ+1=0$ I get $e^{iθ}$ and $e^{−iθ}$ then I try to find characteristic vector by trying to find $v$ such that $Av=v\operatorname{exp}(iθ)$ which ultimately leads me to calculation similar to finding $P$ such that $PA=BP$ but I want to avoid that bad calculation and want to tackle this using operation on matrices if possible.

Comment: This operation is called diagonalisation. Have you heard about that?

Comment: @Arthur How to diagonalize this particular matrix?

Comment: You can't be asking this if you *have* heard about it: you're supposed to try first. And if you fail, explain why. And if you haven't heard about it, read about it, then try.

Comment: @ArnaudMortier I know the definition only but I do not find any smart process other than manually calculation $P$ such that $PA=BP$.

Comment: @Arthur If I try to find the roots of $\lambda^2-2\lambda cos\theta+1=0$ I get $e^{i\theta}$ and $e^{-i\theta}$ then I try to find characteristic vector by trying to find $v$ such that $Av=ve^{i\theta}$ which ultimately leads me to calculation similar to finding $P$ such that $PA=BP$ but I want to avoid that bad calculation and want to tackle this using operation on matrices if possible.

Comment: @ArnaudMortier If I try to find the roots of $\lambda^2-2\lambda cos\theta+1=0$ I get $e^{i\theta}$ and $e^{-i\theta}$ then I try to find characteristic vector by trying to find $v$ such that $Av=ve^{i\theta}$ which ultimately leads me to calculation similar to finding $P$ such that $PA=BP$ but I want to avoid that bad calculation and want to tackle this using operation on matrices if possible.

Comment: Well the process that you just described is a very neat one. If you want to avoid this particular method, then it should be mentioned in the body of the question.

Comment: @ArnaudMortier I am looking for a smarter approach.

Comment: To find $P$ is to find the eigen row-vectors of $A$, as that is what its rows are. So there is no "smarter" method of finding $P$ than to find the eigenvectors. Besides, for $2 \times 2$ matrices, this is not a "bad calculation". It you want guidance, try [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eigenvalue_algorithm#2%C3%972_matrices).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Knowing eigenvectors it's straightforward.

To save our time, we can reason as follows

All matrices $A_{\theta}$ pairwise commute and are diagonalizable. Then there is a common matrix $P$ (that does not depend on $\theta$) that diagonalizes all these matrices. Then, to find such a matrix $P$,  it suffices to diagonalize

$A_{\pi/2}=\begin{pmatrix}0&-1\\1&0\end{pmatrix}\rightarrow diag(i,-i)$.

EDIT. Answer to the OP's comment. OK, I understand..

Then put $P=\begin{pmatrix}a&b\\c&d\end{pmatrix}$ and solve $P\begin{pmatrix}0&-1\\1&0\end{pmatrix}=diag(i,-i)P$.

Then $P$ depends on 2 parameters; randomly choose them and (except if you are particularly unlucky) the obtained $P$ is invertible and works for any $A_{\theta}$..

Comment: I have yet not studied eigen values only have an intuitional idea about it and I have yet not learnt diagonalization.